# Styling with Emotion in React gives ":nth-child" is potentially unsafe when doing server-side rendering error

Tags: css, reactjs, storybook, emotion

Using [Emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction) for a **React** project I'm styling a particular `div` element with `padding-bottom` as the following:

```
export const StyledItem = styled('div')(() => ({
  '&:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)': {
    paddingBottom: '1px'
  }
}))
```

And getting the following error message in **Chrome**'s console:

> The pseudo class `":nth-child"` is potentially unsafe when doing server-side rendering. Try changing it to `":nth-of-type"`.

See the screenshot from the console:

[image: error-screenshot]

The following change resolves the issue and removes the error message from the console:

```
export const StyledItem = styled('div')(() => ({
  '&:nth-of-type(1) > div:nth-of-type(1)': {
    paddingBottom: '1px'
  }
}))
```

See the dependencies from *package.json*:

```
"dependencies": {
   "@emotion/core": "^10.0.28",
   "@emotion/styled": "^10.0.27",
   "react": "^16.13.1",
   "@storybook/react": "^5.3.13",
   /* other dependencies */
}
```

**Question:**

So the suggested change for the error message resolved the issue. Also checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57239807/the-pseudo-class-first-child-is-potentially-unsafe-when-doing-server-side-ren) and [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/6998) already which are not giving me a clear explanation.

The question is why is that error message has shown if the things are happening on **client side** and not on **server side** as the message states? Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When SSR renders the components, it also renders style elements along with it. The first child of the component may be a style element and using `n-th-child` could potentially be unsafe as it would be unintended behaviour.

[EmotionJS GitHub Issue](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/1059#issuecomment-444566635)