# Trippled Image Effect on hover with MUI

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

There is this Codepen with a working tripple hover effect on an image: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/krakruhahah/pen/dymzGmB)

When I try to rebuild it as styled component on React Typescript with MUI and MUI Image accepted by MUI I am getting an error in my style={...} and cant get it to work in my React App. Can anyone help why? I declared my css in a const styles and apply it inline.

`App.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Box } from '@mui/material';
import Image from 'mui-image';

const styles = {
   body:{
       background: "#3d4552",
       fontFamily: "arial",
       fontSize: "12px",
       color: "#fff",
   },
   
   img: {
       border: "1px solid #d2d2d2",
       padding: "3px",
       boxShadow: "0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,.1)",
   },
   
   picContainer: {
       maxWidth: "210px",
       maxHeight: "210px",
       margin: "50px",
   },
   
   pic: {
       background: "#fff",
       position: "absolute",
       transition: "all 0.2s ease",
       backfaceVisibility:"hidden",
   },
   
   "pix:nth:child(1)": {
       zIndex: 3,
   },
   
   "pic:nth-child(2)": {
       zIndex: 1,
   },
   
   "pic:nth-child(3)": {
       zIndex: 2,
   },
   
   "picContainer:hover .pic:nth-child(1)": {
       transform: "rotate(15deg)",
       transition: "all 0.5s ease",
   },
   
   "picContainer:hover .pic:nth-child(2)": {
       transform: "rotate(7deg)",
       transition: "all 0.10s ease",
   },
   
   "picContainer:hover .pic:nth-child(3)": {
       transform: "rotate(-5deg)",
   },
   
   picCaption: {
       background: "#82a3d4",
       padding: "10px 15px",
       color: "#fff",
       fontSize: "12px",
       position: "relative",
       zIndex: "10",
       top: "90px",
       left: "200px",
       borderRadius: "3px",
       transition: "all 0.5s ease",
       opacity: 0,
   },
   
   "picCaption:hover": {
       background: "#607fae",
   },
   "picContainer:hover .pic-caption": {
       left:"230px",
       opacity: 1,
   },
   
};

function Hover() {

   return (
<Box style={styles.picContainer}>
   <Image src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" style={styles.pic}  />
   <Image src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" style={styles.pic} />
   <Image src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" style={styles.pic} />
</Box>
   );
}

export { Hover };
```

**The error:**

```
(property) MuiImageProps.style?: React.CSSProperties | undefined

Type '{ background: string; position: string; transition: string; backfaceVisibility: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'.
  Types of property 'backfaceVisibility' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'BackfaceVisibility | undefined'.ts(2322)

index.d.ts(28, 5): The expected type comes from property 'style' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & MuiImageProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'
```

Comment: When you say "am getting an error in my style", what error are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I minified the `styles` object by removing unused or erroneous styles such as `picCaption` or `pix:nth:child(1)`.  I've also replaced all occurrences of `:nth-child()` with `:nth-of-type()` since [nth-child is potentially unsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63487167/styling-with-emotion-in-react-gives-nth-child-is-potentially-unsafe-when-doin).

For this solution there are only two relevant style objects, `picContainer` which will be applied to the outer `<Box/>` and `img` for the mui `<Image/>` wrapper. The `pic` class can be referenced inside the styling object. We can make use of nesting to avoid repetition, analogous to *scss* this also works here.

```
const styles = {
  picContainer: {
    maxWidth: "210px",
    maxHeight: "210px",
    margin: "50px",

    "&:hover": {
      ".pic:nth-of-type(1)": {
        transform: "rotate(15deg)",
        transition: "all 0.5s ease",
      },
      ".pic:nth-of-type(2)": {
        transform: "rotate(7deg)",
        transition: "all 0.10s ease",
      },
      ".pic:nth-of-type(3)": {
        transform: "rotate(-5deg)",
      },
    },
    ".pic": {
      position: "absolute",
      transition: "all 0.2s ease",
      backfaceVisibility: "hidden",

      "&:nth-of-type(2)": {
        zIndex: 1,
      },
      "&:nth-of-type(3)": {
        zIndex: 2,
      },
    },
  },
  img: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    border: "1px solid #d2d2d2",
    padding: "3px",
    boxShadow: "0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,.1)",
  },
};
```

Now since its my first time working with `<Image/>` from `mui-image` I found it tricky here. The image gets wrapped inside a MUI image class which comes with its own styling. Using `wrapperClassName` and custom `width`, `height` was necessary here to avoid the image from being expanded and stretched.

```
// Hover.tsx

  return (
    <Box sx={styles.picContainer}>
      <Image
        wrapperClassName="pic"
        width={150}
        height={150}
        src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"
        style={styles.img}
      />
      <Image
        wrapperClassName="pic"
        width={150}
        height={150}
        src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"
        style={styles.img}
      />
      <Image
        wrapperClassName="pic"
        width={150}
        height={150}
        src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"
        style={styles.img}
      />
    </Box>
  );
```

The result is identical to the Codepen that has been provided in the question:

[image]

Comment: Wow your explanation makes so much sense to me right now thanks for the help!