# Can you use :nth-of-type without a selector and get the same functionality as :first-child?

Tags: css, material-ui, emotion

Trying to address a console warning I'm getting from MUI5/emotion (I think)

```
The pseudo class ":first-child" is potentially unsafe when doing server-side rendering. Try changing it to ":first-of-type".
```

So I was curious, what happens if you omit the selector in `:first-of-type`? I don't see any difference when I do this. Maybe it's ok?

**EDIT:**
^ This is my question and it is not answered in the question that is being linked too. I only included the emotion bit for context.

Comment: Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66124825/17182878) to a similar question, maybe it will help you understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it has something to do with browser compatibility. The pseudo class `:first-of-type` https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type is understood by all browsers. Whereas `:first-child` is not supported by some. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child

Comment: this is not true, both selector have the same compatibility and support (even for some old browser)